# How can I get column name from specific Mysql table in Array

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I am trying to retrieve column names from mysql databse. I can get column name like this:

```
Array ( [id] => id [BSPKey] => BSPKey [PrintPost] => PrintPost [Barcode] => Barcode [FirstName] => FirstName [LastName] => LastName [Add1] => Add1 [Add2] => Add2 [Suburb] => Suburb [State] => State [Zip] => Zip [Team] => Team [Dteam] => Dteam [Fteam] => Fteam [DPID] => DPID [Error] => Error [Address1] => Address1 [Address2] => Address2 [correct3] => correct3 [correct4] => correct4 [correct5] => correct5 [fcorrect] => fcorrect [bspprint] => bspprint )
```

to get this I use this script

```
$qColumnNames = mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW COLUMNS FROM newdata");
$numColumns = mysqli_num_rows($qColumnNames);
$x = 0;
while ($x < $numColumns)
{
    $colname = mysqli_fetch_row($qColumnNames);
    $col[$colname[0]] = $colname[0];
    $x++;
}

print_r($col);
```

But I want only column name and want to populate html `<select>` element like this

```
<select name="column_name[]" multiple="multiple">
<option selected="selected" value="id">id</option>
<option selected="selected" value="BSPKey">BSPKey</option>
<option selected="selected" value="PrintPost">PrintPost</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Barcode">Barcode</option>
<option selected="selected" value="FirstName">FirstName</option>
<option selected="selected" value="LastName">LastName</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Add1">Add1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Add2">Add2</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Suburb">Suburb</option>
<option selected="selected" value="State">State</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Zip">Zip</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Team">Team</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Dteam">Dteam</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Fteam">Fteam</option>
<option selected="selected" value="DPID">DPID</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Error">Error</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Address1">Address1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Address2">Address2</option>
<option selected="selected" value="correct3">correct3</option>
<option selected="selected" value="correct4">correct4</option>
<option selected="selected" value="correct5">correct5</option>
<option selected="selected" value="fcorrect">fcorrect</option>
<option selected="selected" value="bspprint">bspprint</option>
</select>
```

Hope someone has an easy solution.

Comment: Have ou actually tried it? Where are you blocked?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate over the array you've got at the end (`$col`). Just use `foreach` on this array and populate the `HTML` like this,

```
<select name="column_name[]" multiple="multiple">
<?php
foreach($col as $key=>$val) {
    ?>
         <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Result of the above code would be same as you need. It is just displaying the `<option>` for each element of the array using it's `key` and `value`.

Comment: Thanks mate, it just did the job

Comment: Great, Please accept it as correct answer if it helped you.